# sfdx force:source:push -u globalschema --ignore warnings --forceoverwrite

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, sfdx-plugin, sfdx-error

I am used to using this command:
sfdx force:source:push -u globalschema --ignore warnings --forceoverwrite

Now I am getting this error

Warning: We plan to deprecate this command in the future. Try using the "project deploy start" command instead.
Error (1): Nonexistent flag: --ignore
See more help with --help

I am not sure what command to use. What is eveyrone using now??

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error, it's a warning. You are being advised to use [`project deploy start`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_project_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_project_deploy_start_unified). That looks like this:

```
sfdx project deploy start
```

Or

```
sf project deploy start
```

Note that `sf` is now the preferred tool over `sfdx`.

Comment: but what if I want to force ignore and push, would that work?

Comment: @sdfxconfuseduser Yes, this command has a number of options. The default mode is push, and you can specify options like ignoring errors or forcing overwrites. See the link in my answer for all the possible options.